# Как спроектировать иерархию классов, чтобы сделать простым добавление свойств в базовый класс?

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Товарищи, подскажите, как в приличном обществе принято решать такую задачу:

Имеем, например, такую иерархию классов

```
class A_Base
{
  int x;
  int y;

  public A_Base(int x, int y) 
  { 
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class A_First : A_Base
{
  string name;

  public A_First(int x, int y, string name):base(x,y) 
  { 
    this.name = name; 
  }
}

class A_Second : A_First
{
  string surname;

  public A_Second(int x, int y, string name, string surname):base(x,y,name)
  {
    this.surname = surname;
  }
}
```

Теперь нам понадобилось в A_Base добавить ещё одно свойство (и соответственно, инициализировать его в конструкторе)

```
class A_Base
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;

  public A_Base(int x, int y, int z) 
  { 
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}
```

Значит, придется во всей иерархии классов менять определение конструктора, дописывая туда новый параметр z, хотя сами эти конструкторы мы не меняем - меняем только вызов родителя. И как-то это не очень хорошо.

```
class A_First : A_Base
{
  string name;

  public A_First(int x, int y, int z, string name):base(x,y,z) 
  { 
    this.name = name; 
  }
}
```

Как у продвинутых ООП-товарищей принято поступать в подобных случаях?
Заводить отдельный класс/структуру, которая будет параметром для конструктора?

```
class A_Init
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
}

class A_Base
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;

  public A_Base(A_Init init) 
  { 
    this.x = init.x;
    this.y = init.y;
    this.z = init.z;
  }
}
```

или есть ещё какой-нибудь хитрый паттерн?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr**

> > Решений может быть несколько, и зависят они от конкретной ситуации.

В данном конкретном случае я бы обратил внимание на причину изменения спецификации. Откуда появился новый параметр `z`, почему он был не предусмотрен сразу?

Ответ на этот вопрос поможет спроектировать иерархию правильно. Например (вариант №1), эксперты предметной области не могут описать все возможные сценарии. Это означает, что по мере работы над программой свойства будут появляться и изменяться, и *это совершенно нормально с точки зрения бизнеса*. Тогда да, структура типа `A_Init` будет подходящим решением.

С другой стороны, если эта структура хранит значения по умолчанию для параметров `x`, `y`, `z`, то не лучше ли сразу сделать в иерархии пустой конструктор или конструктор только с самыми необходимыми параметрами, список которых *точно не будет изменяться* ©?

Второй способ корректнее в том числе и потому, что поможет решить ту же проблему на всех уровнях иерархии. `A_Init` не гарантирует, что не придётся заводить `A_Init2` для какого-нибудь из наследников.

Потому: используйте значения по умолчанию везде, где это возможно. Передавайте через конструктор только инициализаторы для `readonly` полей.

Вариант №2: идёт предварительное проектирование системы, пишется *прототип*. Для прототипа не так страшно, что изменения в код вносятся часто. Собственно, для выявления узких мест он и разрабатывается. Тогда ответ: ничего страшного не происходит, так и должно быть.

Третий вариант: наследники являются на самом деле не наследниками, а *декораторами*. Тогда и реализация выглядит по-другому:

```
class A_First : A_Base
{
  A_Base decorating;
  string name;

  public A_First(A_Base decirating, string name)
  { 
    this.decorating = decorating;
    this.name = name; 
  }
}
```

Как понять, что речь идёт об этой ситуации? Обычно так, что `A_Base` является абстрактным классом, который почти ничего не умеет, а вот его наследники и выполняют основную работу.

Четвёртый вариант является расширением варианта первого. В случае, если значения по умолчанию существуют, но алгоритм их получения запутан, логику их получения/вычисления можно вынести в отдельный класс, который Эрик Эванс назвал бы *регламентом*. Тогда все классы иерархии получали бы в конструкторе один или несколько регламентов и инициализировались бы в соответствии с правилами бизнес-логики.

Отличие `A_Init` от регламента не в синтаксисе, но в сути. Если `A_Init` не содержит бизнес-логики, а только возвращает константы, то это, вероятно, не регламент.

Answer (score 10):

Это один из недостатков наследования - если меняется родительский класс, то изменения скорее всего будут влиять на все дочерние. И ничего тут поделать нельзя. Особенно этот недостаток будет проявляться в долгосрочных и крупных программах.

Чтобы избежать таких вещей, можно подумать о замене наследования композицией или ознакомиться с проектированием по принципам SOLID, или посмотреть на другие парадигмы, например *"Компонентно-ориентированное программирование"*.

В последнем каждый класс строится из компонентов, наследование не используется, соответственно проблема исчезает, и вероятность ошибок существенно меньше, но когда компонентов много, то будет сложно в них ориентироваться.

Answer (score 7):

В рамках языка C# — никак. Это частный случай проблемы [хрупкого базового класса](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class).

Вы должны понимать, что изменение базового класса (от которого есть или могут быть где-то производные классы) представляет собой breaking change **всегда**, и требует внимательного пересмотра всего кода.

Поэтому

- старайтесь планировать заранее базовые публичные открытые для наследования классы так, чтобы их публичный интерфейс не нужно было менять в будущем;
- старайтесь сопротивляться таким изменениям;
- если всё же изменений базового класса не избежать, оповещайте всех возможных клиентов вашего базового класса о ваших изменениях, чтобы они пересмотрели свой код; старайтесь делать изменения так, чтобы на место, в котором требуется изменение, указывал компилятор.

  - плохой пример: ваша функция принимала угол в градусах как число типа `double`, теперь она принимает угол в радианах также как число типа `double`
  - пример получше: ваша функция принимала угол в градусах, теперь у вас появилась функция с новым именем, которая принимает угол в радианах, а старая маркирована атрибутом `[Obsolete]`

И да, модификация базового класса нарушает [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) из SOLID.